# Django- Retrieve all details from mysql database

Tags: mysql, django, django-views

I have a Django application connected to MySQL database.
**In the MySQL database I have a table called Evaluation with eval_id, eval_name, and date as its columns.**

From my Django view, I am trying to get the relevant data with the below code.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from .models import Teacher, Subject, Evaluation, Teaches, eval_summary

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
   eval_list = Evaluation.objects.all()
   return HttpResponse(eval_list)
```

Here in the output, I am only getting the eval_name entries and not the eval_id and date.
What should I include to get all the details?

My output is just 
2014_Term1 2014_Term2 2014_Term3 2015_Term1 so on.. I also want the ID and date to be associated with each entry.

Also if I want to get a particular entry how can I get it with all the attributes?

**Evaluation.objects.get(eval_id=1) only returns the name.**

Comment: you can try `.values()` method. Eg. `eval_list = Evaluation.objects.all().values('eval_id', 'eval_name','date')`.

Comment: Also can you let me know how i can get all the fields when i try to use Evaluation.objects.get(eval_id=1)?

Comment: Check the code I posted as answer.

Comment: `values` is not the correct answer here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman OK now I am confused. Why you are talking about templates only when it is mentioned nowhere in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.values()`.

To get all values, you can do something like -

```
eval_list = Evaluation.objects.filter(<your condition>).values('eval_id', 'eval_name','date')
```

Eg. To get all values of objects with *eval_id=1*, do -

```
eval_list = Evaluation.objects.filter(eval_id = 1).values('eval_id', 'eval_name','date')
```

Comment: Also is it possible to link the 2 models and fetch data? Previously i would write SQL queries to link the tables and get data. How can i do this in Django without inserting raw SQL queries? Is it even possible?

Comment: By linking, do you mean using values of foreignKey or m2m field? If yes, then yes. You can get values using `.values()` and `__` notation. See here [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Comment: I have 3 tables, teacher, subject and a teaches table(with teacher_id and subject_id as foreign keys). Now if i want to get all the teachers and subjects they teach how do i link it? Previously with SQL i used `select teacher_id,name,subject_id from teacher,subject,teaches where(teaches.teacher_id = teacher.teacher_id and teaches.subject_id = subject.subject_id)`

Comment: That query would be something like - `teaches.objects.filter(teacher__id=<teacherId>).values()`. However if you ask a new question regarding this, better discussion can be done.

Answer (score 0):

This question is based on a complete misunderstanding; and, contrary to the previous answer, you **do not** need to use `values`.

When you output an object on the template, you see its default string representation as defined by the `__str__` method. In your case, that is showing the name only.

But the other fields are *still there* and you access them via normal attribute lookup. For example:

```
{% for eval_object in eval_list %}
    {{ eval_object.eval_name }}
    {{ eval_object.eval_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So does that mean in my template(say html file) i will have to access individual values? But what if I want to do some processing on the data received in my views.py file?

Comment: What? I was answering your question. You can of course access the values in your view as well, in exactly the same way by using the standard dot notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do that. I want to display this data in the form of a table. Previously I ran raw SQL query and returned the result in json format.

Comment: Well you should use a template then, surely?

Comment: Yes i need to do that. The table needs to be populated by this data. And my intention of this view is that it serves as an API to it. I'm a newbie to Django so a bit confused with it.